# Returning datatable and a string

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to return a datable which should include a string , manually adding a string when returning a datable , below is the code i am using:

```
static public DataTable GetInfoByCode(string code, string user)
    {

    string sql =    "SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName,  " +
                    "Code.dateUsed" +
                    "FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN" +
                    "aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN"+
                    "rAccessCode ON aspnet_Users.UserId = rAccessCode.userID INNER JOIN"+
                    "Code ON rAccessCode.CodeID = Code.accessCodeID"+
                    "WHERE (Code.accessCode = code)";

                    MembershipUser userPass = Membership.GetUser(user);
                    string password = userPass.GetPassword();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt; //want to return password field in the dt so that i can link datasource with datagridview and show password and username in gridview
        }
```

I want to add password in the dt so that I retrieve the password field in datagrid view like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="password" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="Password" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is the password hashed or cleartext?

Comment: You cannot show a hashed password in cleartext, so what do you want to show?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting one, and only one row back in your data table, you can make the following amendment:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
//Add the password column:
dt.Columns.Add("password", typeof (String)); 
//set the value:
dt.Rows[0]["password"] = password;
//Now return your datatable
```

This will add an additional column to the DataTable called `password` which you then set the value for.

However, in your original example, I can't see where you are filtering on the username. A query like the following should help here:

```
string sql =    "SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName,  " +
                "Code.dateUsed " +
                "FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN" +
                "aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN"+
                "rAccessCode ON aspnet_Users.UserId = rAccessCode.userID INNER JOIN"+
                "Code ON rAccessCode.CodeID = Code.accessCodeID"+
                "WHERE (Code.accessCode = @code)";


                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connstring"))
                {
                    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.Text = sql;

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);

                        connection.Open();

                        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            dt.Load(reader);
                        }

                    }


                }
```

Note the query has been parameterized such that we only attempt to return the row matching the user's code. If no such row exists, you would want to cater for this (if `dt.Rows.Count == 0` for example)

However, I agree with other posters, there is no reason why you shouldn't represent this as a custom user object - you can still data bind this to the display. For example:

```
public class User{

  public string UserName { get; set; }

  public string Code { get; set; }

  public string PasswordHash { get; set; }


  public User()
  {

  }


}
```

And then, during load:

```
User user = new User();     

using(...)
{
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {   
                user.UserName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("UserName"));
            }     
        }
    }

user.PasswordHash = userPass.GetPassword();
user.Code = code;
```

where using(...) is shorthand for the outer using blocks.

There is also no reason why this could not be `List<User>` too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to return object that will hold all wanted values, and then bind the datagrid to list of such objects. But if you want to stick with DataTable solution you can add column (or add it to select like in my example below) and fill it with password data. btw. it seems that this query will return DataTable with just one row :

static public DataTable GetInfoByCode(string code, string user)
    {

```
string sql =    "SELECT aspnet_Users.UserName,  " +
                "Code.dateUsed, Password as '' " +
                "FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN" +
                "aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN"+
                "rAccessCode ON aspnet_Users.UserId = rAccessCode.userID INNER JOIN"+
                "Code ON rAccessCode.CodeID = Code.accessCodeID"+
                "WHERE (Code.accessCode = code)";

                MembershipUser userPass = Membership.GetUser(user);
                string password = userPass.GetPassword();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      dt.Rows[0].SetField<string>("Password", password);
    return dt; //want to return password field in the dt so that i can link datasource with datagridview and show password and username in gridview
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If a single record is always returned then you could do

```
dt.Columns.Add("Password");
dt.Rows[0]["Password"] = password;
```

otherwise you will have to loop through your record and assign the password